# How can I resolve connection error during docker swarm join command?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm using two servers, A and B.

The two servers are connected with ssh connection.

I ran the below command at server A:

```
> sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr SERVER_A_IP

Swarm initialized: current node (i3ob4imfipqcfm6l713shaem4) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join \
    --token SWMTKN-1-2ru3tokyxfyep1ifp8diir89x8i94o0py5fcoaue12ep43tvy3-dls3jomzc2bh2by2f2s02i7y5 \
    SERVER_A_IP:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

And then the below command at server B:

```
> sudo docker swarm join     --token SWMTKN-1-4s757ln39s1lkeu7xy8ucmv7rweqte4odedb4xi7x4fettu8sh-0wskijh5rzh42zxzbjs1hxfjr     SERVER_A_IP:2377
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

What does this error mean?

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

I set firewall options for the both servers:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=2376/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=7946/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=7946/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=4789/udp --permanent
```

I searched for this error, and tried another command at server A, and failed:

```
> sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr SERVER_A_IP --listen-addr SERVER_B_IP
Error response from daemon: failed to listen on remote API address: listen tcp SERVER_B_IP:2377: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

result of netstat command:

```
> netstat -tuplen
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=11000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17082      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:873             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16129      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65130           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          19486      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65131           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18964      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          46782      -
tcp6       0      0 :::544                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          48400      -
tcp6       0      0 :::873                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16130      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          46791      -
tcp6       0      0 :::2105                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          48398      -
tcp6       0      0 :::543                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          48399      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60823           0.0.0.0:*                           0          17469      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37406           0.0.0.0:*                           0          48150      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          17486      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49238           0.0.0.0:*                           0          48323      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*                           0          17081      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          18058      -
udp6       0      0 :::1106                 :::*                                0          17470      -
```

Any thought appreciated :)

Comment: are both the machines in a local network? and are you using public ips or private?

Comment: @MuhammadHasan I'm using private IPs. The two machines are made at Cloud service.

Comment: --advertise-addr
This flag specifies the address that will be advertised to other members of the swarm for API access and overlay networking. If unspecified, Docker will check if the system has a single IP address, and use that IP address with the listening port (see --listen-addr). If the system has multiple IP addresses, --advertise-addr must be specified so that the correct address is chosen for inter-manager communication and overlay networking.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure your swarm's network does not overlap with your machine's network